# Web2py + MS SQL Server 2008 R2 + LDAP Authentication HelloWorld application?

Tags: python, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, web2py

I have been using Web2py in the awesome *nix environment for sometime along with opensource RDMS (MySQL,Postgre,SQLLite,etc) for my personal projects.

For my workplace which is completely working in a .Net environment I need to make a quick web app (employee master data maintenance) which runs on the local intranet with authentication and user roles.

I planned to develop the application on web2py and deploy it on the default rocket server BUT am stuck with the DAL. I have tried pyodbc, mssql, mssql2 adapters and all work arounds people have done on the google Group and other forums.

My production and deployment environment details are:

O/S: MS Windows Server 2008 
DB: MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (hosted over LAN and with Windows Authentication not SQL Authentication) 
Python: 2.7 
WebServer: IIS 7.0 ideally but I can work on Rocket.

Is there any 'HelloWorld' application tutorial out there which covers these topics:

1. Windows Domain Authentication with user roles in Web2py
2. Web2py-to-MSSQLServer2008R2 DAL
3. Web2py-IIS7.0 Deployment

If someone can help me I can post this as a web2py appliance once I am done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, it only deals with authentication using Active Directory (I assuma it is the same or similar to Domain Authentication). I am not a Windows expert, but had the local windows admin help me. This is code that I put in the db.py file for this app in web2py.

```
if localauth:
    # I set localauth to 1 when using the app on my home lan, else 0
    # I am a consultant and not always connected to the client VPN
    # FYI, I do have a db of same type and name with same user/pw at home
    # in this case use the basic login that comes as default with web2py
    pass
else:
    from gluon.contrib.login_methods.ldap_auth import ldap_auth
    auth.settings.login_methods = [ldap_auth(mode='ad',
                                             server='<server ip address>',
                                             base_dn='<base_dn>')]
    # the above line forces active directory to be the ONLY authentication method
# my base_dn looked like this: 'OU=<ou>,DC=<subdomain>,DC=<domain>,DC=<tld e.g. com, net, edu, etc.>'
# an active directory knowledgeable person can help you here
```

Jay

Comment: Note that if you want to pick up AD group membership, you need to add additional parameters: manage_groups=True, group_member_attrib='member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:'

Answer (score 0):

Yep Jay's right for the LDAP part.  I did have to make one modification to the ldap_auth.py login method to get it working on our domain, but it seems not everyone needs it.  See https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!searchin/web2py/LDAP/web2py/jyFl1CXUy0s/TXld4CEdlEcJ  There is also a (very simple) how-to at http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/145

Web2py's DAL has worked just fine with MSSSQL 2008 R2 for me just put the connection in models.py

```
#tell the dal where your MSSQL db is
db = DAL('mssql://username:password@db_server/database_name')
```

BUT I am using a SQL Server authentication and not Windows authentication. Checking the [pyodbc connection string docs](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings) it looks like it may be possible by adding Trusted_Connection=yes to your connection string - haven't tried yet myself and might require modifications to gluon/dal.py

And define your tables - refer to the official documentation http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06

I don't know about the IIS part - it has come up a few times in the [web2py Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!searchin/web2py/IIS) and there's a how-to at http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/128 that may be helpful. Personally I just run web2py under Apache even on Windows though.

I would strongly recommend asking on [web2py's google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#forum/web2py), you'll get much more attention.

Comment: OK, after some testing it seems possible to get the DAL to connect to the database using Windows authentication (of the currently logged in user).  This did require a change to gluon/dal.py to get it to allow you to skip the username.  I'll try to submit this to Massimo for inclusion in web2py.

Comment: Thanks! 

Let me put all of this input together into a complete application which can work as a helloWorld for running web2p in a an enterprise intranet environment hopefully. Any more notes on the above are  welcomed.

Comment: Brian,<br/><br/>Did you get a chance to send this to Massimo?<br/>Please send me your current files with the changes to DAL incorporated so that I move forward with the project. I didn't get a response on the Google Group. The moderators didn't approve my post. Thanks!